# Reorder parallel arrays

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays: `A`: `[3 4 1 2]` and `B`:`[7 2 1 4]`. Now I have a reordering of `A` as `[1  4 2 3]`. Let's call this ordering `A2`. What's a good way to order `B` such that the elements of `B` are still aligned with the elements of `A` in the new ordering `A2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

```
A = [3 4 1 2];
A2 = [1 4 2 3];

B = [7 2 1 4];

[~, C] = ismember(A, A2);
B = B(C);

B =
     1     2     4     7
```